# Python decorator composition

Tags: python, function, python-decorators

Below is an example code demonstrates how decorators work. It takes a function `get_text(name)` and wraps it with a function `p_decorate(func)`.

I have trouble understanding how the function p_decorate knows that the parameter `name` is a supplied argument of `func`? Since `func` in definition of `p_decorate` has no arguments? Can someone please explain. So far I know how decorators work with functions without parameters, but this is causing me a headache.

```
def get_text(name):  #This is fine                                                                    
    return "lorem ipsum, {0} dolor sit amet".format(name)                                

def p_decorate(func):                                                                    
    def func_wrapper(name):   #How does it know that name is part of func?                                                           
        return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(name))                                           
    return func_wrapper                                                                  

my_get_text = p_decorate(get_text)                                           

print my_get_text("John")
```

Output:

```
<p>lorem ipsum, John dolor sit amet</p>
```

Comment: The developer hard-coded the name. Python only knows this because the *author of the code put that name there*.

Comment: But the function definition p_decorate has no idea to what "name" belongs to. Sorry if I am unclear but that is my issue.

Comment: It's just a local variable. It belongs to `func_wrapper()`, no-one else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer that wrote that decorator hard-coded the name. Python only knows this because the *author of the code put that name there*. It's just a symbolic name for a local variable.

In other words, there is nothing magical about naming a function argument. You could have named it something completely different and the code would still work just the same:

```
def p_decorate(func):
    def func_wrapper(arg1):
        return "<p>{0}</p>".format(func(arg1))
    return func_wrapper
```

Note that that variable has no relationship to the `name` local variable in the `get_text()` function! Again, that's just a local variable name in *that* function. For positional arguments, all that matters is the relative position of the argument when calling. The first value passed into `functioncall(...)` is assigned to the first local variable name inside the called function.

All this is not anything special to decorators, this applies to **all** functions.

Comment: Oh sorry of course...I had another stroke of idiocy. It will always work as long as the function supplied to func expects a single argument. Thank you